# Mouse cursor & video display issues since upgrading to Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade, video, mouse, display, lubuntu

A couple of months ago I dist-upgraded my Laptop (a Lenovo X201) fro Lubuntu 15.10 to Lubuntu 16.04. Since that time, I've had the following problems:

- On resume after suspend, typically the mouse cursor disappears - but it is responsive, it's just not drawn. If I switch VTs and back to the X server's VT I see the cursor again.
- Occasionally (can't see exactly when) video players will show a blank, black frame and pretend everything is fine (e.g. audio will play). This is not resolved by switching VTs, nor by switching from the laptop's display to an external monitor and back, or the other way around. Only rebooting (and maybe restarting just the X server) makes the problem go away.

Are these issues related? Can I fix them or circumvent them somehow?

Comment: The final release of Lubuntu 16.04 was less than 2 months ago. Are you sure you Upgraded "a couple of months ago"? You might be working with some (buggy) beta version if you did.